# JSON to CSV Conversion for a huge file

Tags: powershell

I do not have Powershell experience. Looking for some help to convert a huge JSON file to CSV.
I tried the below code which I found online, however it throws below error.

Code Snippet:

```
$file = "C:\Users\Desktop\Fk9b3ug5u\records.txt"
$pathToOutputFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\Fk9b3ug5u\Fk9b3ug5u.csv"

((Get-Content -LiteralPath "C:\Users\Desktop\Fk9b3ug5u\records.txt") | ConvertFrom-Json).results |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
Set-Content $pathToOutputFile
```

---

Error :

> ConvertTo-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
>       At C:\Users\sneshah\convertJsonToXML.ps1:5 char:5
>       +     ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
>       +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToCsvCommand

Comment: "results" would be an object in the JSON.  Does records.txt have an object named results?  If you are just trying to get the entire file, you would remove ".results" from your script.

Comment: [`Json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a data structure that supports recursive objects in comparison to a [`CSV` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) which is a table existing of primitives/strings and doesn't support any complex objects. Meaning you can't  just convert a (part of a) `JSON` file into a `CSV` file unless the concerned object property (`Result`) is a flat object property. To determine that you will need to share the `JSON` in your question. See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @philselmer - Thank you so much, that worked, I removed the results and it generated the csv file.

Comment: Glad that worked.  I posted the solution as an answer.  If you feel that is sufficient, please mark it as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @philselmer - Sure I will. 
However I just noticed there are few fields for which underlying fields get clubbed. Is there a way to resolve that?
Do I need to create another thread for this or I can continue in the same thread?

For eg : JSon 

"TotalCost":{"AppAmtInBaseCurr":200.0000000000,"Amt":200.0000000000,"Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},

Output csv: 
Row Header 'Total cost' and entire below content of the cell is 
@{AppAmtInBaseCurr=200.0000000000; Amt=200.0000000000; Currency=}

Comment: As IRon pointed out, JSON is not natively compatible with CSV unless the collection of objects is flat.  I would think you need to create a custom script to parse through the JSON and pick out the fields you need.  I would suggest researching JSON and understanding how the format works.  Then if you still need help, ask another question.

Comment: Thank you iRon & @philselmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted, results is an object inside JSON.  If your records.txt doesn't contain that object, you won't have any data when you try to get it with `.results`.  If the entire file is able to be converted to CSV, you will just need to remove `.results` from your script.